# How do I access members of a Javascript object numerically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Let's say for example, I have the following Javascript object:

```
var Object = {
   Person_A: { name: 'James', age: 40, country: 'Spain' }, 
   Person_B : { name: 'Smith', age: 50, country: 'France' } 
}
```

I want to know how many properties there are in the object `Object`, and access these properties numerically e.g. through `Object[n]`.

Until now (I don't use Javascript objects much, but I do use JSON as a return format when working with AJAX) I didn't know that Javascript objects don't have a `length` method and can't be accessed numerically.

I've tried to convert the Javascript object into the same type of JSON that is returned when I make AJAX calls (the JSON is returned as an object with a length method, and is numerically accessible - **just read another thread, and maybe I'm wrong about this - double checking now**) using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object))` but that simply returns the same exact Object.

So, my question is, what's the most efficient way to take an object like the example, and make it accessible numerically and have a `length` method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (and please ask if you need any clarification of my question).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function numericIndices(obj) {
    var i=0, x;
    for( x in obj) {
        obj[i] = obj[x];
        i++;
    }
    // next line is OPTIONAL:
    obj.length = i;
}
```

Given an object, this will add the numeric indices to that object. So after running it through that function, the object will have both string keys and numeric keys. If you have the optional line too, you automatically get a `length` property as well.

Comment: Hi, it would be interesting to see what the resulting objects looked like (in JSON format). Do they still retain the original keys as a property of an object in the array? Also, this would show how your solution differs from the others.

Comment: Keeping it simple, if you give it `{a:'hello'}` then the output is `{a:'hello',0:'hello',length:1}`. It differs from 2unco's answer because theirs creates a new array that *only* has the numeric indices. If this is what you want, go with theirs. If you'd like to have both available, use mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, just used it, it's really a fast and efficient solution :).

Comment: I'm glad it works. Just be careful not to pass the same object through that function twice, because that would lead to unpredictable and possibly destructive results.

Comment: The properties here should be enumerable for this code to work, is it?

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be done with meaning. The properties of JavaScript objects have no inherent order<sup>1</sup>.

The `length` property is a *special* member of Arrays. (Arrays are just objects that have a specific [[prototype]] and understand how to magically update `length` -- and have a few other internal rules defined -- that's it!)

---

Update for comment:

If the index is required, use an Array:

```
var people = [
   { id: "Person_A", data: { name: 'James', age: 40, country: 'Spain' } },
   { id: "Person_B", data: { name: 'Smith', age: 50, country: 'France' } }
]

people[0].id // "Person_A"
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  JSON "has order" *only when serialized as text* but implementations, including those that turn it into JavaScript objects, work without access [or assumption] about order; there is *no order guarantee for properties* per the JSON standard. Just because properties in an object "look" ordered in JSON (or a JS Object Literal), does not imply an order.

Comment: So, in the case of the above object, would you recommend a different way of formatting the data? I don't need any methods within the object, just a simple way to store values, and access them with ease.

Comment: @Avicinnian I've updated with an example. As can be seen, the "id" could be folded into the primary ("data") structure, but I left it separate for comparison.

Comment: Huge thanks for the in-depth example! Now I understand a fundamental difference between arrays and objects (something that I've been wondering for a while)

Comment: @Avicinnian: with respect to ordering, it's not so much a difference between objects an arrays. It's more that if you assign numeric indices as properties, that gives you a mechanism to enforce order. Array literal syntax just happens to assign the numeric properties automatically, but you still need to properly iterate the array in order to guarantee an order. You can get the same ordered iteration from a plain object, but an Array just makes it a little (or a lot?) more convenient.

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks for filling in the details :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely replace that object with an array accessible numerically, you could first loop through it to build that new array:

```
var newArray=new array();
for(i in object){
    array.push(i);
}
```

You can now access that array numerically

Comment: Hi, it would be interesting to see what the resulting objects looked like in JSON format. Do they still retain the original keys as a property of an object in the array? Also, this would show how your solution differs from the others.

Comment: This actually sacrifices the keys PERSON_A and PERSON_B, you're losing data/specificity by implementing an array. The solution by @Kolink doesn't sacrifice this, but I'm worried about how that loop would work (I think it's obj[i]=x; not obj[i]=obj[x], but I'll leave that to you to test). So Kolink's is more powerful